# Help in an example of Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

So here is an example from the Ross' A First Course In Probability 8th ed.
[image]

Why did the author pick $k=10$ in part b? For that matter, how does one know which $k$ to pick when doing problems involving Chebyshev's Inequality?

Comment: Because the exercise says "between 40 and 60" and the mean is 50 and 60=50+k and 40=50-k for k=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{P}(40<X<60) = \mathrm{P}(-10<X-50<10) = \mathrm{P}(|X - 50| < 10)$